# How to change excel number delimiter formatting defaults

Tags: microsoft-excel

Today my excel number formatting automatically formats the number as below

`1000000 --> 10,00,000`

I want to change the number formatting to automatically format as per the million's standard as

`1000000 --> 1,000,000`

Any ideas?

Location: India (I am assuming it takes up Lakhs delimiter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question is more suited for superuser.

Also it is not a setting in Excel, but a regional setting in OS (I assume you use Windows).

Go to *Control Panel -> Clock and region -> Change date, time, or number formats -> Additional settings*

Under *Number* tab find *Digit grouping:* and choose `123,456,789` from the list.
Under *Currency* tab also find *Digit grouping:* and choose `123,456,789`

Press `OK` and `OK`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it worth checking the format cell
Right click on your cell -> Format Cells ...

I tried quickly and some formats can give the formatting you have. You can try to change the format or even try the currency tab

[Excel exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEI7x.png)

Answer (score 0):

Lakhs delimiting indeed has something to do with the way that thousands and others are grouped together, but this is not just to be dealt with in Excel, it should count for all applications on your PC.

[This link](https://excelchamps.com/excel-basics/apply-comma-style/#Change_the_Comma_Style_Separators_from_Lakhs_to_Million_format) explains how to deal with that (you should jump immediate to the right place on the page).